# Setting up JupyterHub on K8s: Can I forward the user to different node pool (cpu vs. gpu)

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter, google-kubernetes-engine

I am currently investigating whether it's worth to setup Jupyter on K8s. I came across this website: https://z2jh.jupyter.org/en/latest/index.html. One of the questions I have is forwarding a user to appropriate node pool. I will have 2. One is with CPU running and one with GPU active. I don't want all of the users to be automatically using GPU but rather reserve GPU for couple of data scientists that actually need it. Everyone else should be using CPU node-pool.

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to either forward the user to appropriate nodepool based on his credentials, or any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side note:  I definitely think it is worth setting up Jupyterhub on Kubernetes if you plan to have multiple users and want to dynamically scale your resources rather than manual or pre-provisioning environments for each user.

To answer your question, it is possible to set things up in a way which meets your requirements.

You'll need to:

1. Set up at least two [different profiles](https://z2jh.jupyter.org/en/latest/jupyterhub/customizing/user-environment.html#using-multiple-profiles-to-let-users-select-their-environment) (one for CPU only and one for GPUs).  In the profile for GPUs, you'd use the [extra_resource_guarantee](https://jupyterhub-kubespawner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spawner.html#kubespawner.KubeSpawner.extra_resource_guarantees) property of the `kubespawner_override` to set the GPU guarantee.  Alternatively, you can use the [node_affinity_required](https://jupyterhub-kubespawner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spawner.html#kubespawner.KubeSpawner.node_affinity_required) property to only choose nodes with GPUs (assuming nodes are labeled) or you can use the [node_selector](https://jupyterhub-kubespawner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spawner.html#kubespawner.KubeSpawner.node_selector) property (for example, with GKE you could set this to select nodes with specific types of GPUs using the key `cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator`)
2. Enable [user-dependent profiles](https://z2jh.jupyter.org/en/latest/jupyterhub/customizing/user-environment.html#user-dependent-profile-options) such that only select users will see the GPU profile option.

Comment: Thank you. If I set two different profiles, I assume they have to be done on the same node pool, correct? So, I would create nodepool with GPU and limit that GPU to the users that actually need it, correct? AFAIK, I cannot create a nodepool with GPU on separate nodes only; thus node_affinity might not work.

Comment: Are you actually using GKE?  In that case, you'd have one nodepool with GPUs and one nodepool without GPUs.

Comment: Correct, using GPU. Thank you. I am trying to see how I can switch between nodepools based on the user. I guess, node_selector/node_affinity is the answer.